# Correct way to initialize settings in .net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I created an REST api application which has many settings and stored in database. These settings are used during filtering and inserting data to the table.

Because I need to access settings every time I need to insert data. Instead of accessing settings from database, I created a global settings class and I put every settings in that class.

```
public static class GlobalSettings
{
    public static string Setting_1;
    public static string Setting_2;
    public static string Setting_3;
    public static string Setting_4;

    public static void Initialize(ISettingsRepo repo)
    {
        try
        {
            var settings = new GSettings(repo);
            Setting_1 = settings.SetSetting_1();
            Setting_2 = settings.SetSetting_2();
            Setting_3 = settings.SetSetting_3();
            Setting_4 = settings.SetSetting_4();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error when loading settings.\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `ISettingsRepo` is scoped service that will load the settings from database. The functions will initialize the settings to the properties.

Now to initialize `GlobalSettings` I used configure method in startup class like this.

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                Settings.GlobalSettings.Initialize(scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<Data_Repo.Settings.ISettingsRepo>());
            }
```

Now I can use this in controller or anywhere in my api and get settings without accessing database. Also I can reload the `GlobalSettings` any time if settings are updated. But does this method correct way or has memory leak problems?

Is there any better method to do this.?

Comment: You can use the [`IOptions pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as described here

Comment: Can you store options in database instead of appsettings ?

Comment: @AjitHegde there's nothing special about `appsettings`. It's just a file. .NET Core configuration [can read configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from any number of providers, including a database. The [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-configuration-provider) example shows how you can create an provider that reads from a flat Key/Value table.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestions. It is much easier to use configuration with CustomConfiguration provider.

Comment: Also I should mentions that reload on change is not implemented for the database custom configuration providers. That means I have to restart the server to update the settings. While above solution works fine even if I updated the data.

Comment: How will you use `GlobalSettings` while inserting data? How did you reload `GlobalSettings` if  there is setting updated? You should avoid using static object.

Comment: Settings can be only updated by admin. After updating database I reassigned the static objects.

Answer (score 4):

Example

My appsetting.json have structure like this.

```
"EmailSettings": {
  "MailServer": "",
  "MailPort": ,
  "Email": "",
  "Password": "",
  "SenderName": "",
  "Sender": "",
  "SysAdminEmail": ""
},
```

I will define my class like this

```
public class EmailSettings
{
  public string MailServer { get; set; }
  public int MailPort { get; set; }
  public string SenderName { get; set; }
  public string Sender { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string SysAdminEmail { get; set; }
}
```

So we have the the config structure. The last thing we need is register inside Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
```

To use it inside service class

```
private readonly IOptions<EmailSettings> _emailSetting;

public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSetting)
{
  _emailSetting = emailSetting;
}

email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailSetting.Value.SenderName, _emailSetting.Value.Sender));
```

Comment: This is good. It does work with database. But does it allow to reload the settings without having to restart the server to get the updated settings from database.

Comment: This approach is use to read config from json file. Using this approach when you add new value into json file you can reload website and you will have new value

Comment: Microsoft provides an example of [defining a custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-configuration-provider) to load config from a database using EF.

Comment: I already know that and implemented it. But this method does not implement reloadOnChange method